# Asynchronous Progress bar updating

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

This is a vb.net mvc 3 application.. I am new to asynchronous and threading combined so this is a bit over my head on 2 levels... I have a long running process that sends mass emails at set intervals to avoid terms of use violations.. Not only for this task but for other options I would like to add a progress bar that is updated through java..I have found a blog post about doing something like this... I have got the following code but there seems to be an issue where the progress bar is never showing...

Below is my extendedTaskRun Class:

```
   Imports System.Collections.Generic
   Imports System.Linq
   Imports System.Threading
   Namespace ExtendedTaskHandler

''' <summary>
''' Long Running Test Class.
''' </summary>
Public Class extendedTaskRun

    Private Shared syncRoot As New Object()

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the process status.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The process status.</value>
    Private Shared Property ProcessStatus() As IDictionary(Of String, Integer)
        Get
            Return m_ProcessStatus
        End Get
        Set(value As IDictionary(Of String, Integer))
            m_ProcessStatus = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Shared m_ProcessStatus As IDictionary(Of String, Integer)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="extendedTaskRun"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        If ProcessStatus Is Nothing Then
            ProcessStatus = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetStatus(ByVal id As String, ByVal value As Integer)
        SyncLock syncRoot
            ProcessStatus(id) = value
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Processes the long running action.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id">The id.</param>
    Public Function ProcessLongRunningAction(id As String) As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 100
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            SyncLock syncRoot
                ProcessStatus(id) = i
            End SyncLock
        Next
        Return id
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds the specified id.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id">The id.</param>
    Public Sub Add(id As String)
        SyncLock syncRoot
            ProcessStatus.Add(id, 0)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes the specified id.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id">The id.</param>
    Public Sub Remove(id As String)
        SyncLock syncRoot
            ProcessStatus.Remove(id)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the status.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id">The id.</param>
    Public Function GetStatus(id As String) As Integer
        SyncLock syncRoot
            If ProcessStatus.Keys.Where(Function(x) x = id).Count = 1 Then
                Return ProcessStatus(id)
            Else
                Return 100
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Then my controllers are as follows:

```
        Public Function MassEmailStatus() As ActionResult
        MassEmailAddressList = TempData("emailaddresses")
        TempData.Clear()
        TempData.Add("emailaddresses", MassEmailAddressList)
        Return View()
    End Function

    Public Function MassEmailSendingStatus(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        Dim d As List(Of String) = TempData("emList")
        Dim EmailCount As Integer = d.Count
        Dim triedCount As Integer = 0

        Dim extendedTaskRun As New extendedTaskRun
        extendedTaskRun.Add(id)
        Dim percentDone As Integer = 0
        While Not (triedCount = EmailCount)
            For Each em In d
                EmailSender(em, String.Empty)
                triedCount += 1
                percentDone = EmailCount / 100 + triedCount
                extendedTaskRun.SetStatus(id, percentDone)
            Next
        End While
        extendedTaskRun.Remove(id)
        Return View()
    End Function
```

Then the MassEmailStatus view is as follows:

```
  @Code 
ViewData("Title") = "MassEmailSendingStatus"
TempData.Add("emList", TempData("emailaddresses"))
end Code

 <div>
 <a href="#" id="startProcess">Start Long Running Process</a>
 </div>
 <br />
<div id="statusBorder">
<div id="statusFill">
</div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var uniqueId = '@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()';
  var tdata = '@TempData("emailaddresses")';
          $(document).ready(function (event) {
          $('#startProcess').click(function () {
              $.post("MassEmailSendingStatus", { id: uniqueId }, function () {
              $('#statusBorder').show();
              getStatus();
          });
          event.preventDefault;
      });
  });

  function getStatus() {
      var url = 'Admin/GetCurrentProgress/' + uniqueId;
      $.get(url, function (data) {
          if (data != "100") {
              $('#status').html(data);
              $('#statusFill').width(data);
              window.setTimeout("getStatus()", 100);
          }
          else {
              $('#status').html("Done");
              $('#statusBorder').hide();
              alert("The Long process has finished");
          };
      });
  }

</script>
```

These are the additional functions that the blog mentioned and are in my code but from looking at the code I know they cannot be correctly wired up.

```
    Private Delegate Function ProcessTask(id As String) As String
    Private extendedRunClass As New extendedTaskRun

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Starts the long running process.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id">The id.</param>
    Public Sub StartLongRunningProcess(id As String)
        extendedRunClass.Add(id)
        Dim processTask As New ProcessTask(AddressOf extendedRunClass.ProcessLongRunningAction)
        processTask.BeginInvoke(id, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf EndLongRunningProcess), processTask)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Ends the long running process.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="result">The result.</param>
    Public Sub EndLongRunningProcess(result As IAsyncResult)
        Dim processTask As ProcessTask = DirectCast(result.AsyncState, ProcessTask)
        Dim id As String = processTask.EndInvoke(result)
        extendedRunClass.Remove(id)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the current progress.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id">The id.</param>
    Public Function GetCurrentProgress(id As String) As ContentResult
        Me.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        Dim currentProgress = extendedRunClass.GetStatus(id).ToString()
        Return Content(currentProgress)
    End Function
```

I do know that Im not actually starting the process as im just calling `EmailSender(em, String.Empty)` which is where the work occurs,  inside the for each loop of the MassEmailSendingStatus controller... What must I do to fix this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

WOW my code was whacked...After taking the blog code and throwing it in a quick project of its own and starting it i was able to watch what was happening.. I have it working now... I will update this with the working solution in a bit... Working on returning more than just percentage to the progress bar now so messages are displayed as its working.. Not sure how im going to do that but im thinking I will do it inside the getCurrentProgress method as a string return from the extendedTaskRun class...